# Is there any difference between "lower-latin" and "lower-alpha" values of "list-style-type" CSS property?

Tags: css, html-lists

Both `list-style-type: lower-latin` and `list-style-type: lower-alpha` results in list like this:

```
a. item1
b. item2
c. item3
...
```

Is there any difference between these two values, or they are exactly the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/PR-CSS2-19980324/lists.html#list-props) doesn't note any difference. `Lower-latin` could be a new attribute. I'm not sure, but they display the same, so I'd say they are the same.

Note that IE8 and earlier versions won't display `lower-latin`.

[QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/lists.html) doesn't provide a definitive answer.

If anyone has any ideas, let us know? Seems strange to have two attributes that appear to do the same.

Maybe they're for different character sets?

See also:

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-type_ex

Answer (score 4):

W3C section about this is here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/PR-CSS2-19980324/lists.html#list-props

Quoted in part from the above link location (note ***or***):

> Alphabetic systems are specified with:
>
> ```
> lower-latin or lower-alpha
>     Lower case ascii letters (a, b, c, ... z). 
> upper-latin or upper-alpha
>     Upper case ascii letters (A, B, C, ... Z).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

probabely the expression "lower-alpha" is showing the listing points in the language in which the system is set. This is not necessarily Latin. But to display the listing points, regardless of the language setting in Latin is probably provided "lower-latin".  I don't have another explanation.

Comment: I tried forcing different languages with the `lang` attribute but there don't seem to be any differences, even for Greek (`lang=en`).

Answer (score -1):

They are synonymous. See description from W3C:

```
Alphabetic systems are specified with:

lower-latin or lower-alpha
  Lower case ascii letters (a, b, c, ... z).
...
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/PR-CSS2-19980324/lists.html#list-props

HT: to @Hitch above.